# How can I replace this shower drain cover?

Tags: shower, drain, rust

The drain cover that covers the vertical tub/shower overflow drain came off the other day, and it looks like the screw holding it in is rusted. I’m not sure any of my normal rusted screw removing skills will work in this tight space (and it’s not obvious what will be there if I do remove it - will it be something I can then screw into still?).  The drain pipe is plastic. Probably 1980s construction.

Any suggestions for alternative covers or alternative attachment methods that don’t involve replacing piping or calling a plumber??

[image: picture of drain with rusted screw]

Answer (score 0):

The only way to properly repair it will involve getting access to the back of the tub to replace the overflow assembly.  Hopefully the other side of the wall is in a closet or someplace inconspicuous.

Cut a clean square hole at least 16 x16 inches. You can then frame the cut piece and replace it, allowing easy access in the future.

Once you get access, you may be able to remove the overflow tube and get the screws out for simple replacement.  If not have a new assembly ready for replacement.